# Making dark overlay fade in (HTML/CSS/React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this overlay component

**Overlay.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Overlay.css'

const Overlay = props => <div
    className="overlay"
    style={{
        display: props.show ? 'block' : 'none',
    }}></div>;

export default Overlay;
```

**Overlay.css**

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
```

What I want is for the overlay to fade in (from opacity 0 to 0.7) whenever I set its show property to true. What I have tried now does not work (adding the transition in the css file). Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that you are not changing opacity value but switching the display of the element.

My suggestion is that you use css animations.

```
@keyframes custom-fadein {
  0%   {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0.7;}
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    animation-name: custom-fadein;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

Now anytime you change display property from none to block it will show de div object and it will start the animation.

Hope it helps!

**ADDED**

To handle the fadeout too you could do the following

```
@keyframes custom-fadein {
  0%   {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}

@keyframes custom-fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.shown{
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: block;
    animation-name: custom-fadein;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

.hidden{
    display: block;
    animation-name: custom-fadeout;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

And instead of alternate with the display state of the element, you can alternate between the classes shown or hidden.

Comment: Sorry I have to ask again. I've also added a fadeout keyframe (that does the reverse of custom-fadein). But it does not apply when I switch to display none again, any idea why?

Comment: It's the same as your earlier problem, setting an element to display none it's equivalent to "removing" it from the document. In that case I think you could do as I added in the answer

Answer (score 2):

you are on the right direction, the only issue is that you modify `display` property instead of `opacity`.

When you apply `transition` to an element by opacity property - element should appear with `opacity: 0` and afterwards opacity should be changed to `opacity: 0.7`. In such case, you will see diming effect.

Here is a code sandbox that demonstrates this scenario. https://codesandbox.io/s/wnrokmvw55